# right aligned icon button inside side nav

Tags: html, css

This should be simple, but I'm having problems please help me to solve this as I am completely new to CSS and its attributes.

Basically, I want to have a button inside side nav with a width equal to side nav and when I click onto it, it should display a  list just below it.

but Now I am getting as follows,

[image]

and here is the html,

```
<div class="page">
  <div>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="toolbar">
      <div>
        <button class="menuButton" mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
        <span class="companyName">Hello</span>
      </div>
    </mat-toolbar>
  </div>

  <mat-sidenav-container class="sideContainer" fullscreen  autosize style="top: 80px !important;">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="push" opened="false" class="sideNav">
      <nav class="sidenavbutton">
        <button cls="btn">Dashboard <i id="icon" class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
      </nav>
    </mat-sidenav>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

and corresponding css is,

```
.example-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.toolbar{
  background-color: transparent;
}
.menuButton {
    color: black;
}
.companyName {
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: orangered;
}

.yaanapage{
  background-color: orange;
}

.sideNav {
  height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 30%; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  background-color:orangered; /* Black*/
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}
.menuItems {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background-color:orangered;
  margin: .5em;
  padding: .3em 0;
  height: 1.6em;
  color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 2%;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.btn {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: none;
  background-color: #535B99;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
}
#icon {
  float:right;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: try making `.btn` have `display: block;`

Comment: @zgood, made changes, but same output I am getting

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your button needs to have the name `class` not `cls` didn't work in jsfiddle at least.

Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/7cry40j6/)

Second of all I used the click function from JS/jQuery to display the `ul`.

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    $(".sidebar-list").addClass("visible");
});
```

Here it is with vanilla JS

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
     document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.add('visible');
}
```

------ Toggle the menu ------

You can toggle the `ul` with `.toggle()` with jQuery.

Here is a [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7cry40j6/1/)

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn").click(function(){
      $(".sidebar-list").toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Did it answer your question though? @Anil

Comment: how to show the list just below the button and for first click it should display list and next click it should hide again, please help me to do

Answer (score 0):

If you changed cls to class it works as you described it should. And I might add a `display:block;` to the .btn class as well.